# Querying XML in SQL Server

Tags: json, sql-server, xml, t-sql, xquery

I'm a newbie to SQL Server. I have a table `Accounts` which is defined as:

```
OrganizationId int,
AccountDetails varchar(max)
```

The `AccountDetails` column contains XML data.

The data in the table looks like this:

```
1 | <Account><Id>100</Id><Name>A</Name></Account>
2 | <Account><Id>200</Id><Name>B</Name></Account>
3 | <Account><Id>300</Id><Name>C</Name></Account>
4 | <Account><Id>400</Id><Name>D</Name></Account>
```

I need write a SQL query to get the records from this table where `AccountId` is 200 or 400.

The query should return two rows (#2 and #4) in JSON format, like this:

```
result1 : { "account_id": 200, "account_name": B }
result2 : { "account_id": 400, "account_name": D }
```

I'm wondering how do I go about this?

Thank you.

For # 1 above, should I be trying to cast the `AccountDetails` column to XML type and then use "nodes" feature for querying/filtering?

For #2, I should be writing a SQL function to convert the XML to JSON first and querying XML to build the JSON as needed?

Comment: Aside... that's a horrible schema for storing XML data. Not only is it inefficient to convert text to XML whenever you need to query it (XML is stored in a special format by SQL server) but by using a char/varchar data type like that you'll likely clobber international characters. Save yourself some time and trouble, use the correct `xml` data type.

Comment: #1: yes. #2: no, deserialize from XML to native values first, filter your result set, then use `FOR JSON` to serialize the filtered results to JSON.

Comment: Building on the comments from @AlwaysLearning store your values in their own, relational columns and not in XML at all! That won't help with your current predicament, but there are XML functions available in sql server.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: Thank you Yitzhak for your valuable feedback! Noted, going forward.

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned, it is much better to use a proper XML data type for the **AccountDetails** column.

Please try the following solution.

It will work starting from SQL Server 2016 onwards.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (OrganizationId INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, AccountDetails NVARCHAR(MAX));
INSERT @tbl (AccountDetails) VALUES
('<Account><Id>100</Id><Name>A</Name></Account>'),
('<Account><Id>200</Id><Name>B</Name></Account>'),
('<Account><Id>300</Id><Name>C</Name></Account>'),
('<Account><Id>400</Id><Name>D</Name></Account>');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

;WITH rs AS
(
    SELECT t.OrganizationId
        , account_id = x.value('(/Account/Id/text())[1]', 'INT')
        , account_name = x.value('(/Account/Name/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(20)')
    FROM @tbl AS t
        CROSS APPLY (VALUES(TRY_CAST(AccountDetails AS XML))) AS t1(x)
)
SELECT *
    , JSONData = (SELECT rs.account_id, rs.account_name FOR JSON PATH,WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER)
FROM rs
WHERE rs.account_id IN (200, 400);
```

**Output**

| OrganizationId | account_id | account_name | JSONData |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 200 | B | {"account_id":200,"account_name":"B"} |
| 4 | 400 | D | {"account_id":400,"account_name":"D"} |

Comment: Thank you  for your inputs on this. For #1, I was trying below  earlier, but keep getting "unable to switch encoding" error. I shall try your approach. Thank you! 

select * from Account where cast(Replace(AccountDetails, 'UTF-8', 'utf-16') as xml).exist('/Account[Id=200]')=1